# Managing a Tag Manager container with Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We are in a situation where we need to restrict whole Tag Manager from loading on certain pages.

Problem is that we don't have anything fixed method to do this.

I ended up thinking that could it be possible to manage a Tag Manager container with Tag Manager?

I could configure it to follow different triggers and administer variables that could hold different values e.g. allowed or disalloed subdomains.

And adding some subdomain restrictions to every single tag is out of the question.

Comment: This can be done with zones but is for 360 clients only
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7647043?hl=en

Comment: Great, nice to know about these special features.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new feature called "[Zones](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7647043?hl=en)" that basically allows you to link GTM containers to the container that is embedded via the snippet. You can load the linked container based on variables (urls, datalayer variable etc). Also for each Zone you can set restrictions as to what types of tags, triggers and variables are allowed (like the blacklisting feature for the tracking code).

The main disadvantage is that every linked container contains the full GTM boilerplate (which add 50kb zipped or thereabouts to your page weight), and that there is a danger that actions in one container have side effects on the other.

But it seems for your use case you could create a default configuration (or even an empty container) that is shared across all your properties and then attach a zone for your respective subdomains.

As pointed out in the comment to the OP this is a 360 feature (360 has a list prices of some 120K p.a. for the lowest tier, so this is rather an enterprise option).